# How do I pass a constructor to a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

The question says "Add a constructor to the Point class that accepts another Point as a parameter and initializes the new Point to have the same (x, y) values. Use the keyword this in your solution."

```
public  class Point
{
  int x;
  int y;
  //enter your code here
}
```

What I have applied all the concepts I can think of and hit and trial method,but none of them  worked. I mean how can I pass a constructor to a constructor! 
This is the best I came up with.

```
 public Point(Point)
 {
     this.x=x;
     this.y=y;
  }
```

But this generates an error. 
  "< identifier> expected
public Point(Point)"

Comment: Do you want to call nested Constructor.

Comment: And hint: you aren't passing constructors to constructors. And honestly: such things are nicely explained in any good book. You are expected to do serious research prior posting questions here.

Comment: @syedHamzaHassan No, I wanted to call a constructor which has the same constructor of the same class as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor should be:

```
public Point(Point p) {
    this.x = p.x;
    this.y = p.y;
}
```

This way you assign `p`'s attributes to your class's attributes.  
You did not include the identifier `p`.   
Although if this is the only constructor of the class then the class is useless since it needs a preinstantiated object in order to instantiate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

At least you need to give a constructor parameter variable a name:

```
public Point(Point p) {
 this.x = p.x;
 this.y = p.y;
}
```

You don't have to pass a constructor to constructor, just an instance is enough to copy it.
Instance of the class has an access to all the private fields of the same class